# Changing List elements in a For loop

Tags: python-3.x, list

This script works for what I need it to, but while researching how to make this I found many comments that it is the wrong way to do this.  The comments that I found are not very descriptive, and don't really seem to apply to my use case.  I can't put my finger on if or why this is wrong, what can I do to improve this?

```
myList1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myList2 = [1, 3, 5]
myList3 = []

for i in myList1:
    myList3.append(0)
for j in range(len(myList1)):
    for k in range(len(myList2)):
        if myList1[j] == myList2[k]:
            myList3[j] = 1

print(myList3)
```

My output is what I want:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

So I want to make myList3 to be the same length as myList1, and populate it with zeros.

I want to then compare myList1 with myList2 and if there are matches, then that element number of myList1 receives some value.

Maybe there is nothing wrong with this and the reason I can't find an answer is that it's just fine?

Comment: You might try at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't do this. You're not modifying any lists that you're iterating over, and that's fine.

A shortcut for initializing `myList3` with the same length as `myList` and populated with `0`s is simply: `myList3 = [0] * len(myList1)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your approach. However, there is no need for so much explicit looping and testing:

```
myList1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myList2 = [1, 3, 5]
myList3 = [1 if element in myList2 else 0 for element in myList1]
```

This basically merges the two loops walking myList1 (once for 0 and once for comparison), and removes the loop to search myList2 for matches. Using such a style is usually preferable, as it is largely about what you want, not how to get there.

Note that depending on how much data you have, you want `myList2` to be a `set`. A `set` has constant time for lookups, whereas a `list` is fast for few elements but slows down with more elements.

```
myList1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mySet2 = {1, 3, 5}
myList3 = [1 if element in mySet2 else 0 for element in myList1]
```

Comment: Or maybe `myList3 = [int(element in myList2) for element in myList1]`.

Comment: Thank you!  This is simplified from the script that I’m writing, List1 is going to be a json that lives with this script, and List2 is a json that comes from an api call.  The actual comparison will be a unique identifier on both lists, and if present List3 will get appended with a hex number, not a 1.  Thank you for your feedback, I’ll take it to heart.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in `O(len(myList1) * len(myList2))` time which might constitute a problem when lists are large enough (and coincidental elements are evenly spread in `myList2`). One simple optimization would be to turn `myList2` into a set in advance:

```
mySet2 = frozenset(myList2)
myList3 = [1 if element in mySet2 else 0 for element in myList1]
```

This code would have a notably better `O(len(myList1) + len(myList2))` average running time.

Answer (score 0):

I mean technically there is nothing wrong with this at all. It is just a little bit strange that you are using `for i in myList1:`, as you don't really use `i` for anything. I liked @MisterMiyagi's answer in terms of how succinct it is, but if you are just looking for a simple way to intialize `myList3` you could have just done `myList3 = [0]*len(myList1)`.